# Duplicate artifacts in azure devops release pipline

Tags: azure-devops, build, azure-databricks, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-artifacts

I am just doing a CI/CD process for Azure data bricks. For Build I selected Agent job as windows latest with pool windows-latest and Added a step publish build artifacts.
[image]

When I selected release pipeline with same windows agent and pool is from Azure pipelines. After that 2 step for azure data bricks in second step deploy notebook to data bricks three dots when I selected it populated two same paths which is confusing.

[image]

what I am missing why these two linked artifacts are showing here.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the same issue in release pipeline.

[image]

When you select the file, it shows duplicate artifacts and they have the same content. The feature should have some issues.

Refer to this Developer Community ticket: [Azure Devops release pipeline issues while using ARM template deployment for Data factory](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Azure-Devops-release-pipeline-issues-whi/10078277). This issue has been reported by other users and is being investigated by the Azure DevOps team.

You can monitor the ticekt and check the update.

Comment: I will follow but didn't seen any solution and this started happens with me from last two week. Before that it was showing only one artifacts

Comment: I have checked the ticket, the issue has been reported to Product Group. It has no solution for the time being.

Comment: I have not seen any updates to developer community.